# How do I add nontransparent element on transparent element?

Tags: php, html, css, element

Okay so I have "http://hastebin.com/julayefoto.xml" and I want the thing that says "Test Test Test" to be non transparent but the bubble to be transparent. Can anyone help? Thanks :)

Comment: make a fiddle for us to easier edit :)

Comment: Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself**.   Although you have provided a [**link to an example or site**](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254428/something-in-my-web-site-or-project-doesnt-work-can-i-just-paste-a-link-to-it), if the link were to become invalid, your question would be of no value to other future SO users with the same problem.

Answer (score 0):

Add `opacity: 1` to the css class `one`.

```
div.one {
    color: white;
    position: relative;  
    width:100%;
    font-family: arial;
    opacity:1;
}
```